# Drawable resource not found after minify enabled in android app

Tags: android, resources, drawable, minify, shrinkresources

buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources = true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
debug {
debuggable true
testCoverageEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}

**Me also facing same issue minifyEnabled true shrinkResources = true**

```
fun updateImage(context: Context, imageName: String, imageView: ImageView) {
    if (imageView.tag?.equals(imageName.lowercase()) != true) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                context,
                context.resources.getIdentifier(
                    imageName.lowercase(),
                    "drawable",
                    context.packageName
                )
            )
        )
        imageView.tag =
            context.resources.getIdentifier(
                imageName.lowercase(),
                "drawable",
                context.packageName
            )
    }
}
```

How can we resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `shrinkResources` as `false`